# Is there a way to shorten this code to fewer lines?

Tags: python

```
some_var = 0
for i in range(16):
    if 0x7777 >> i & 1:
        some_var += 1
```

Is there a way to shorten this code to use fewer lines? It's a simple variable I want to declare, and just out of curiosity, I'm wondering if I could do something like this in fewer lines.

Comment: yes you can do that in one line using list comprehension style with `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

`some_var = sum(1 if (0x7777>> i & 1) else 0 for i in range(16))`

(edit) recommended improvement ;-)

```
# Count the nonzero bits in 0x7777
some_var = sum(...)
```

Comment: Or `bool(0x7777 >> i & 1)` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Or `some_var = sum(1 for i in range(16) if (0x7777>> i & 1))`